# Send push notification after X minutes using Firebase Functions

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-app-engine, push-notification

I have a mobile app for iOS & Android, and I'm trying to implement a feature that sends a push-notification X minutes after a user exists the app.

In my database, I can already tell when a user is no longer active.

I thought about using App Engine & Firebase Functions & FCM
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html

But it seems that cron.yaml is static (sends notifications on a regular time basis),
And I'm looking for a dynamic approach where I can dynamically decide the time to send the push notification.

For instance - based on some database data, 
1 user will get the notification after 30 minutes of inactivity, 
while other user will get it after 15 minutes.

How can I achieve that specific behavior?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I have done to solve the notification scheduling problem. I have allowed 5 min tolerance (i.e. If you want to send notification on 10:03 then it will be sent on 10:05).

Say you have a function, `sendNotificationFunction(userId, notificationMessage)` , ready which takes `userId` & `notificationMessage` as arguments and sends notification to that particular user.

1. In firebase realtime database, I have made a node which has information regarding the notification schedule:

   ```
   scheduleNotification: {
       <pushId>: {
           "userId":<userId>,
           "scheduledTimestamp":<1530000000000>,
           "notificationMessage":<Message that you want to send>
       }
   }
   ```
2. Make function which will be triggered every5Mins and check which notifications to schedule.

   ```
   exports.every5MinTrigger = functions.https.onRequest((req,res)=>{
       let currentTime = new Date().getTime(); //Say 10:00 
       let startTime = currentTime; //10:00 
       let endTime = currentTime + 5*60*1000; //10:05  
       firebase.database.ref().child("scheduleNotification").orderByChild("scheduledTimestamp").once('value').then((snap)=>{
            if(snap.exists()){
                snap.forEach(childSnap=>{
                    let userId = childSnap.child('userId').val()
                    let notificationMessage = childSnap.child('notificationMessage').val()
                    //Now you have userId and your notification's language. Call your sendNotificationFunction() Here
                })
            }
       })
   })
   ```

   Deploy this function in your firebase cloud functions. And you will get the url of this function let's say it is something like this: `https://us-central1-<your-project>.cloudfunctions.net/every5MinTrigger` .
3. Call this ,`https://us-central1-<your-project>.cloudfunctions.net/every5MinTrigger`, url from your cron job every 5 mins so it will schedule the notifications for next 5 mins.

Hope it helps.